# Xamarin MySQLite - Failed to load errors from the local store

Tags: c#, sqlite, azure, xamarin, offline-caching

I have a local database that looks like this:

[image]

I also have a database in the cloud using Azure that looks like this:
[image]

Whenever I use my function `await client.SyncContext.PushAsync();` which pushes my local database to the cloud, I receive this error:

`Failed to read errors from the local store. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0.`

After some research I have discovered that this is often due to not setting up your `MySQLite` database correctly, but it looks like mine is identical to my cloud database.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As the error states :
`Failed to read errors from the local store. ---> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T`

Please review each of your column's data type for the table. Each of your column's data type must be identical to Type `T`

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Ravindra Kumar, it appears that the reason is because `getTable()` method is pointing to the `/tables` directory in the Azure portal, which is fine when using the Easy Tables software to create a database, but I am not. Do you know how to point my `getTable` method to my MySQL database which is hosted through the Azure portal on ClearDB? Thanks!